# Dropbox isn't started automatically despite the entry on startup applications

Tags: 12.04, startup, dropbox

I've added an entry at the startup applications for Dropbox to run this command:
`dropbox start -i`.

After log on, dropbox isn't started.
Although, when I run this `dropbox start -i` from the terminal Dropbox starts successfully.

Is there any log to see why it didn't start?

Answer (score 1):

Click on the dropbox icon on the top of your screen, hit "preferences" and tick the button where it says "Start dropbox on system startup" in the "general" tab.

If this doesn't work do it command line way :)

Create /etc/init.d/dropbox

```
#!/bin/sh
#dropbox service
DROPBOX_USERS="user1 user2"

DAEMON=.dropbox-dist/dropbox

start() {
   echo "Starting dropbox..."
   for dbuser in $DROPBOX_USERS; do
       HOMEDIR=`getent passwd $dbuser | cut -d: -f6`
       if [ -x $HOMEDIR/$DAEMON ]; then
           HOME="$HOMEDIR" start-stop-daemon -b -o -c $dbuser -S -u $dbuser -x $HOMEDIR/$DAEMON
       fi
   done
}

stop() {
   echo "Stopping dropbox..."
   for dbuser in $DROPBOX_USERS; do
       HOMEDIR=`getent passwd $dbuser | cut -d: -f6`
       if [ -x $HOMEDIR/$DAEMON ]; then
           start-stop-daemon -o -c $dbuser -K -u $dbuser -x $HOMEDIR/$DAEMON
       fi
   done
}

status() {
   for dbuser in $DROPBOX_USERS; do
       dbpid=`pgrep -u $dbuser dropbox`
       if [ -z $dbpid ] ; then
           echo "dropboxd for USER $dbuser: not running."
       else
           echo "dropboxd for USER $dbuser: running (pid $dbpid)"
       fi
   done
}

case "$1" in

   start)
       start
       ;;
   stop)
       stop
       ;;
   restart|reload|force-reload)
       stop
       start
       ;;
   status)
       status
       ;;
   *)
       echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/dropbox {start|stop|reload|force-reload|restart|status}"
       exit 1

esac

exit 0
```

Make sure to change line 3  to your computer username not the dropbox user
`DROPBOX_USERS="user1 user2"`

and on line 5 make sure you got the right execute file in dropbox-dist

'DAEMON=.dropbox-dist/dropbox'

mine had to be DAEMON=.dropbox-dist/dropboxd

Then make the script executable and add it to the system startup:

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/dropbox 
sudo update-rc.d dropbox defaults
```

you can test the script by writing

```
sudo /etc/init.d/dropbox start
```

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply. I tried both of them, but had no success. Firstly, there wasn't such option at Dropbox Settings. Secondly, I did exactly what you've said and not only nothing happened but my other startup options were messed up :/