# Startup applications got messed up - Dropbox and Redshift not loading automatically

Tags: 12.04, startup, dropbox

I have had problems with Dropbox launching at start up, so I've asked [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/398096/dropbox-isnt-started-automatically-despite-the-entry-on-startup-applications).
The problem is that now, after implementing what the user has posted, Dropbox isn't loading and it also messed up other Startup entries, such as redshift. 
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand, you use Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop

Ok. First of all, delete changes you made.

```
update-rc.d -f dropbox remove
```

Dropbox is added to autostart if `dropbox.desktop` file exists in `~/.config/autostart`. Here is my `dropbox.desktop` file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Dropbox
GenericName=File Synchronizer
Comment=Sync your files across computers and to the web
Exec=dropbox start -i
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=dropbox
Categories=Network;FileTransfer;
StartupNotify=false
```

It should be runnable(or ubuntu says it's untrusted launcher), so run `chmod a+x dropbox.desktop`.

Also as @Chris said, he use [CLI script](https://www.dropbox.com/download?dl=packages/dropbox.py) to install dropbox and it was saved in `~/myscripts/` which is not included in `PATH` variable. So he moved this script to `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: I've followed your instructions on creating the dropbox.desktop file, but it didn't work. After reboot, dropbox isn't running. I verified it with this `ps aux | grep dropbox` which returned only the grep process entry. Can you provide any other solution please?

Comment: please, post the output of 'ls -la ~/.config/autostart'

Comment: Also, try to open that desktop file and see if it will start dropbox.

Comment: [Here](http://pastebin.com/5xB67m3v) is the output of ls. Also, I tried running the desktop file with ``grep '^Exec' ./dropbox.desktop | tail -1 | sed 's/^Exec=//' | sed 's/%.//'`` as seen from an answer here, and it opened Dropbox successfully!

Comment: I mean try to open it from nautilus. Press Ctrl+H to see hidden files and go '.config/autostart' folder. It may say that this desktop file is untrusted launcher, if so than you need to add executation permission(Properties->Permissions->Allow executing file as program)

Comment: So, I've tried running it from nautilus and got `Untrusted application launcher. The application launcher "dropbox.desktop" has not been marked as trusted. If you do not know the source of this file, launching it may be unsafe.`. So, I've clicked on Properties > Permissions and then checked the Execute checkbox of the owner. Then, double clicking it gave this `There was an error launching the application. Details: Failed to execute child process "dropbox" (No such file or directory)`.

Comment: I've installed dropbox following the instructions from their site. So I have copied the [CLI script](https://www.dropbox.com/download?dl=packages/dropbox.py) they provide to `~/myscripts` directory. So I think that there might be a problem with this. Where should I copy this script to make it globally available?

Comment: Strange, it says that it doesn't know dropbox. Try to edit this dropbox file and write full dropbox path `Exec=/usr/bin/dropbox start -i`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12800/discussion-between-arhimed-and-chris)